# Unable to execute Phalcon project

Tags: php, phalcon

I have installed Phalcon for PHP 5.6 and I have installed developer tools also. I created a project saying "hello!" from controller. while executing in browser Im unable to get the output. I am just getting the directories and files in that path. Help me out. Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 0):

you need to have a .htaccess file.
in phalcon u need to reference as this docs said https://docs.phalconphp.com/el/3.2/webserver-setup.

if u created a project using developer tools.
u will see .htaccess file and shouldn't getting this error.